# Meteor onrendered do work when using jquery each

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have this code

```
   Template.drone.onRendered(function () {
       var userid = Meteor.userId();

       $('.table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
       var friendid = $(this).find("td:first").html();
       var userid = Meteor.userId();
       alert('this rendered inside each');
       });
      });
```

and this is the template

```
Template name="drone">
               <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Names</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         {{#each allusers }}
            <tr>
                <td class="buttonId">{{_id}}</td>
                <td>{{profile.name}}</td>
                <td class="buttonAction">hi</td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </template>
```

The code above iterates a table and does something useful with the data from the table row,i.e id in each td.

I am wondering why this code `alert('this rendered inside each');` never fires.

Answer (score 0):

I bet `$('.table > tbody > tr')` does not match anythings.

You are on a "parent" template context from your `allusers` iteration. At this stage, your `tr` are not rendered yet.

You should try to do a new template called `userLine`:

```
<template name="userLine">
 <tr>
  <td class="buttonId">{{_id}}</td>
  <td>{{profile.name}}</td>
  <td class="buttonAction">hi</td>
 </tr>
</template>
```

Then, replace your `#each` by:

```
{{#each allusers }}
  {{ >userLine }}
{{/each}}
```

Now, you can use the `onRendered` hook on this new template, and it should fire as you want.